# Is the Descending Fifths sequence also an Ascending Fourths sequence ? Who is the original source of this sequence?

Tags: theory, harmony, history

Can the Descending Fifths sequence also be correctly named as an Ascending Fourth's sequence ?
in major : I - IV - vii dim - iii - vi - ii - V - I
Is Johann Pachelbel (1653-1706) and his Canon in D the original source for this heavenly sequence ?

Comment: Beautiful.  The circle progression.

Comment: Your progression is :  i  -  iv  -  i      =   g  -  c  -  g

Comment: I am so new here . I just realized ggcg is a name for a musician and not a musical progression. Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descending fifths are equivalent to ascending fourths; these intervals are the inversion of each other. Note that in the sequence of roots: C-F-B-E-A-D-G, one can either go C up to F then down to B, up to E then down to A, etc.; or one can go C down to F then Up to B, etc. Either way leads to the same set of roots (but not necessarily notes in the same octave.)

The Pachelbel Canon sequence isn't a sequence of fourths. This sequence dates back at least a century before Pachelbel. His version goes C-G-a-e-F-C-F-G. There are quite a few other similar patterns going under the name "Romanesca." The sequence starts up a fifth, up a second, up a fifth (probably dropping the actual notes an octave) and the up a second, etc. This sequence actually has hits basis in the "rule of the octave" which was just a set of patterns of chords to be played over each note of an octave. The pattern (using a slash to indicate a base not if not the root of the chord symbol) goes like this: C-G/B-a-e/G-f-C/E-F-G. The bass line drops by step from C to E then back to G. In Roman Numerals it's: I-V6-vi-iii6-IV-I6-IV-V. Alternatives are I-V6-vi-I64-IV-I6-ii6-V and others. (The I64 is just another idiomatic use of a 6-4 chord.

Some chord sequences are based on roots; some are based on bass movement; some seem irregular.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the common wordings are:

- descending fifth
- descending fourth
- descending third
- ascending second (or step)

...in other words *descending* intervals except for the ascending step.

Pachelbel is famous but all of these progressions and various *[harmonic sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_(music)#Harmonic_sequences)* - like *Falling Thirds* used in his "canon" - are too old and universal to be ascribed to one person.

Also, @ttw makes a good point to distinguish *root progressions* (at the basic level a two chord movement, a musical bi-gram) and *harmonic sequences* which typically have a two chord progression reiterated and transposed. The Pachelbel example is a *harmonic sequence.*